# ugly import when I use typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, module

I have a problem about ugly imports when i use typescript and when i import a third-party library that made with Javascript and after  install its declaration type file with @types/[library-name] in vscode.

actually i was importing the library to my app when i noticed something wrong.

the import is done from "node_modules/@types/[library-name]".

for example i installed inquirer library with @types/inquirer(package.json)

```
{
  "name": "ch01",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/inquirer": "^9.0.1",
    "inquirer": "^9.1.1"
  }
}
```

then i imported it in my app:
[image]

if you note to path of the import you note that problem.

how do i resolve this problem???

Comment: Is it actually a problem? Does the library still work?

Comment: How is that even a question, @GuillaumeBrunerie? Absolute paths like that _are_ an problem, because that won't work when sharing your code across develpers, or if you want to deploy it anywhere.

Comment: *note that problem* ... what problem?

Comment: @Cerbrus - surely what that image shows is the editor merely telling you where the import is from on the current system, which would be an absolute path - but the path isn't absolute on the import statement, so ... can't see what the issue is, can't even see anything "ugly"

Comment: The absolute path is not present in the code, it's only a VSCode tooltip showing you how this import has been resolved on your own computer. It will show a different absolute path on someone else's computer.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question, I thought there was a full path in the actual import. But yea, that's just the resolved path. Not a problem. My bad.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because That's just the IDE telling you where it found the file.

Comment: No my friend, when i try to compile index.ts file i get an error about this problem. It indicates that is a problem. @Cerbrus

Comment: What is the __exact__ error message?

Comment: when i try compile index.ts file i get an error:  error TS2339: Property 'prompt' does not exist on type 'typeof import("E:/old_windows_data/typescript_project/ch01/node_modules/@types/inquirer/index")'.

2 inquirer.prompt([
           ~~~~~~
This indicates that the error is due to the wrong path resolve by the compiler

Comment: Yea, that absolute path isn't your problem.

Comment: what is the resolve? @Cerbrus

Comment: @Cerbrus i found my problem as you said correct it was just for IDE . thank you a lot.

Answer (score -2):

make sure you installed right version. Inquirer 9 and higher works with that syntax.`const inquirer = require('inquirer');` work for older versions perfectly. If older versions are okay for your code. You must try the older one with that syntax.

If you still want to use 9 and higher. You can use a constructor. It may help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).